# how to use populate with mongoose-paginate while selecting limited values from populated document

Tags: express

I am using mongoose paginate plugin and having a problem while populating other documents. simple population is working properly, but if I want to select **selected** fields, all the fields from populated data is shown and the main document fields are all removed. 
I am using Node Express...

Here is my code.

```
   var page = (req.body.page)?req.body.page:1;
        var perPage = (req.body.itemsPerPage)?req.body.itemsPerPage:10;
        var query   = {};
        var options = {
        select:'typeDesc',
        populate: 'hospitalType',
        lean:     true, 
        limit:    perPage,
        page:     page };
        hospital.paginate(query,options).then( function(result) {
        res.json(result);
        })},
```

[image: Here is the reply from Postman.]

As you can see I only want typeDesc but got all the data and my main data from Hospital was removed.

Comment: what method are you using?

Comment: I am using Post method because of Paginate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Here is the solution**

```
        var page = (req.body.page)?req.body.page:1;
        var perPage = (req.body.itemsPerPage)?req.body.itemsPerPage:10;
        var query   = {};
        var abc = ({ path: 'hospitalType', select: 'field which you want to show' });
        var options = {
        populate: abc,
        lean:     true, 
        limit:    perPage,
        page:     page };
        hospital.paginate(query,options).then( function(result) {
        res.json(result);
        })},
```

I modified your code and change only populate path, the trick here is that you need to describe the document and selected field in other variable and use it in options field.
I can't test it right now as i don't have the database, but i am positive it will work alright. Feel free to comment about this.